# Why is this C# function behaving like I'm using pointers?

Tags: c#, arrays

So I've got this code I'm writing in C#. It's supposed to reverse the order of bits in a bit array (not invert them). Through heavy use of breakpoints and watches, I've determined that the function is somehow modifying both the input parameter array `array` and the array I copied that into in an attempt to make the function NOT change the input array, `tempArray`.

```
static BitArray reverseBits(BitArray array)
    {
        BitArray tempArray = array;
        int length = tempArray.Length;
        int mid = length / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++)
        {
            bool tempBit = tempArray[i];
            tempArray[i] = tempArray[length - 1 - i]; //the problem seems to be happening
            tempArray[length - 1 - i] = tempBit;      //somewhere in this vicinity
        }

        return tempArray;
    }
```

I have no idea why it's behaving like this. Granted, pointers were never my strong suit, but I do try to avoid them whenever possible and they don't seem to be used much at all in c#, which is why I'm puzzled about this behavior.

TL;DR:  if you pass my function `00000001`, you'll be returned `10000000` from the function AND the `array` that was passed from the outside will be changed to that as well

P.S. this is for a FFT related task, thats why I'm bothering with the bit reversal at all.

Comment: BitArray is a reference type,  so you are not making a copy when you do the assignment,  you are duplicating the reference.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you want to create a new instance of a BitArray like this:

```
BitArray tempArray = new BitArray(array);
```

This should create a new instance of a BitArray instead of creating another variable referencing the original array.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't copied the array, you've just assigned it to another variable.

[BitArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx) is a class, and so is always passed by reference (similar to pointers in C/etc).

If you want to copy the array, use the .CopyTo method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this Byte similar function could help you

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Reverse bit order in each byte (8 bits) of a BitArray
        /// (change endian bit order)
        /// </summary>      
        public static void BytewiseReverse(BitArray bitArr) 
        {       
            int byteCount = bitArr.Length / 8;      
            for (int i = 0; i < byteCount; i++) 
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
                {
                    bool temp = bitArr[i * 8 + 7 - j];
                    bitArr[i * 8 + 7 - j] = bitArr[i * 8 + j];
                    bitArr[i * 8 + j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
```